# Indefinite integral $\int \cos^k{x} dx$?

Tags: calculus

From WolframAlpha, we can see
$$\int \cos^k x \;dx = - \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2x}\csc x \cos^{k+1}(x) _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{k+3}{2};\cos^2{x}\right)}{k+1} $$
for any $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is [hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
I want to know its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int \cos^k( x) \;dx =-\int \frac{t^k}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=-\int t^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)! }{\sqrt{\pi }\, n!}t^{2n}\,dt$$
$$I=-\frac 1 {\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int \frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)! }{ n!}t^{2n+k}\,dt=-\frac 1 {\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{n! (k+2 n+1)} t^{k+2 n+1}$$
$$I=-\frac{t^{k+1} }{k+1}\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{k+3}{2};t^2\right)$$

Comment: Great! Could you explain how third equality of first line is induced ?

Comment: @Idkwhat. Binomial expansion of the denominator

Answer (score 0):

This integral can be calculated iteratively:

$$\int \cos^kxdx = \frac{1}{k}\cos^{k-1}x \cdot \sin x + \frac{k-1}{k} \int \cos^{k-2}xdx$$

Comment: I can get a result by using that formula when $k$ is integer. Is that easily calculated when $k$ is not integer ?